# Does the method post() of the object boost::asio::io_service uses the boost::coroutines for short tasks?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Does the method post() method of the object boost::asio::io_service uses the boost::coroutines to perform queue of short-tasks performed in the handlers? This can save the resources spent on synchronization when using threads, but makes it impossible to move tasks to another thread. Or it makes no sense?

Comment: Boost.Coroutine was accepted in Boost 1.53, Boost.Asio - in 1.35. Obviously, the latter doesn't depend on the former.

Comment: @Igor R. Does boost::asio haven't difference between 1.35 and 1.53 versions? Why not take advantage of new opportunities in the old library in its new version?

Comment: @Alex Could you elaborate on what advantages this would provide? While coroutines are excellent for constructing the asynchronous call chains within handlers (and part of the Boost.Asio 1.54 API), I'm having a hard time understanding the gains within the internal event loop dispatch.

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury  I guess we mean the same thing. Do not to use coroutines in the method post(), but to use when you call handler of chain of tasks that have been set by the post(). And will be in boost::asio 1.54 an opportunity to control their use? For example, for short tasks - to use coroutines to reduce the overhead of synchronization, and for a long task - to use threads for load balancing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I could tell, Boost.Asio does not use coroutines.

From an implementation point of view, I would imagine using a coroutine, such as those provided by [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/coroutine/index.html), would introduce overhead when invoking posted handlers.  At the point in which the event loop knows what *handlers* can be invoked, it could simple invoke the handler rather than having to hoist the handler in a trampoline function so that it can be transparently invoked within the context of a coroutine.

Boost.Asio does not know the actual or expected runtime duration of *handlers*, so it must perform the same internal synchronization regardless of the handlers.  When the `io_service` is only being processed by a single thread, then synchronization overhead can be mitigated by providing a [*concurrency_hint*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/io_service/overload2.html) during construction.  Other areas, such as the reactor, may still need to perform synchronization.

In the end, rather than imposing context of execution, Boost.Asio provides a robust toolkit and empowers the users to choose the best option for themselves.  The current Boost.Asio candidate for Boost 1.54 enhances this experience through its first-class support for:

- [Stackful Coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html) based on Boost.Coroutine.  Here is an example where `do_echo` executes within the context of `my_strand` as a coroutine.  Each async operation yields control back to the calling thread after initiating the asynchronous operation, and when the completion handler is invoked, control returns to immediately following the previous yield point.

  ```
  boost::asio::spawn(my_strand, do_echo);

  // ...

  void do_echo(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
  {
    try
    {
      char data[128];
      for (;;)
      {
        std::size_t length =
          my_socket.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(data), yield);

        boost::asio::async_write(my_socket,
            boost::asio::buffer(data, length), yield);
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  ```

  Boost.Asio provides a complete [echo_service example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp) that uses Stackful Coroutines.
- [Stackless Coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutine.html) have been promoted to the documented public API from the [HTTP Server 4 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_4).  These are implemented as a variant of Duff's Device, but the details are cleanly hidden through the use of pseudo-keywords `reenter`, `yield`, and `fork`.  This following is roughly the equivalent of the above Stackful Coroutine example:

  ```
  struct session : boost::asio::coroutine
  {
    tcp::socket my_socket_;
    char data_[128];

    // ...

    void operator()(boost::system::error_code ec = boost::system::error_code(),
                    std::size_t length = 0)
    {
      if (!ec) reenter (this)
      {
        for (;;)
        {
          yield my_socket_.async_read_some(
              boost::asio::buffer(data_), *this);

          yield boost::asio::async_write(my_socket_,
              boost::asio::buffer(data_, length), *this);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  ```

  See the [`boost::asio::coroutine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/coroutine.html) documentation for more details.

---

While I do not know if there are performance benefits to constructing asynchronous call chains with coroutines, I feel as though their greatest contribution is maintainability and readability.  I have found that being able to read and write asynchronous programs in a synchronous manner helps reduce the complexities introduced with inverted flow of control, as it is now possible to remove the spacial separation between operation initiation and completion.

Comment: Thanks! A little question about concurrency_hint: if I created pool with 10 of thread, and in each of them I launch boost::asio::io_service::run, and then if I set concurrency_hint to 20, or to 5, how many threads will use io_service?

Comment: @Alex: Depends.  When the `io_service` implementation uses windows I/O completion ports, the _concurrency_hint_ specifies the max, per [`CreateIoCompletionPort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For the non-Windows IOCP implementation, a _concurrency_hint_ of 1 is the only case where optimizations currently apply.